# Adding two single BCD digits with Verilog

Tags: verilog

Could you please help me finding a Verilog code to add two BCD digits where the output should be BCD as well?

Answer (score 1):

Why not write the code yourself? It's not too difficult, especially if you can find some guidelines online. The code is just a matter of using the logic gates of whichever adder you'd like, depending on but size (RCA is easiest to implement), and then additional logic to break down the numbers being added into single digits, converting to binary, and adding them together. Good luck.